# Simple Method to Open Default Browser in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, browser

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012. With my VB.NET code, I would like to open the user's default browser, bring it to the front and direct it to a particular URL.

Is there an easy way to to do this if you don't know exactly what the browser is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shell execute a URL to open it with the default browser. Something like this:

```
Process.Start("http://google.com")
```

You'll also need a `Imports System.Diagnostics` at the top of your file to import the Process class.

Answer (score 1):

just attach this to a button or the like and target the url to the page you would like and it will open the default browser

```
Dim webAddress As String = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
Process.Start(webAddress)
```

just tried it in studio on vb code and worked fine for me..